# How to use a dirtree inside an enumerate environment?

Tags: enumerate, dirtree

I'm trying to use a dirtree inside an enumerate environment. However, the root will be at a strange location.[image: The output]
My code is as below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dirtree}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item A
    \item B
    \dirtree{%
        .1 a.
        .2 b.
        .3 c.
        .2 d.
    }
    \item C
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Besides, there will be an info:
Overfull \hbox (25.0pt too wide) at [12,1].

I'll new to latex and English is not my native language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not nesting it into a `minipage`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dirtree}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item A
        \item Here is a \texttt{dirtree}\\
                 \begin{minipage}{2cm}
                    \dirtree{%
                        .1 a.
                        .2 b.
                        .3 c.
                        .2 d.
                    }
                \end{minipage}
        \item C
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: dirtree into enumerate]